# How do I make an instance of generic subclass? Getting error: "Bound mismatch: The type ... is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter ..."

Tags: java, class, generics, object

```
public class ChampionsLeague<Team extends Comparable<Team>> extends League<Team>{
...
```

How do I make an instance of this class?

```
ChampionsLeague<Team> league = new ChampionsLeague<>();
```

This does not work:

> "Bound mismatch: The type `Team` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<Team extends Comparable<Team>>` of the type `ChampionsLeague<Team>`"

Answer (score 9):

In your code, `Team` is just a placeholder (in this context, called *Type Variable*) and happens to be *hiding* the type `Team`, not referencing it. In other words, that declaration is equivalent to:

```
public class ChampionsLeague<T extends Comparable<T>> extends League<T> {
```

So it is really only asking for a class (or interface) that implements (extends) `Comparable` of itself. So this example:

```
public class Ball implements Comparable<Ball> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Ball o) { return 0; }
}
// or: public interface Ball extends Comparable<Ball> { }
```

Will work:

```
ChampionsLeague<Ball> test = new ChampionsLeague<Ball>();
```

**Edit:**

Some possibilities to what you may be trying to achieve:

```
// ChampionsLeague needs a type Comparable to Team
public class ChampionsLeague<T extends Comparable<Team>> extends League<T> {
```

or

```
// ChampionsLeague needs a subtype of Team
// In this case, you can make Team implement Comparable<Team> in its own decl.
public class ChampionsLeague<T extends Team> extends League<T> {
```

Comment: Yeah, generics can be really tricky sometimes. I added somme suggestions to help you further. Let me know if you solved both problems (understanding the error and getting what you wanted in the first place).

Comment: @PeterBauer: that means that your question (as it stands) doesn't help you solve your problem (and will probably not help others), so I'll vote to close as "too localized". That doesn't mean that it's a bad question, just that (as it stands) it will probably confuse others more than it helps.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That can be helpful for someone else with the *"Bound mismatch: The type (...) is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter (...)"*